# Counting polygons inside of buffers

Tags: qgis

I have previously asked question here but it was closed because I did not react fast enough I think. NEvertheless, my problem is still the same: I have a set of points (meteorological stations) with 5km buffers around them. Additionally, I have a set of polygons (municipalities) in which those stations are located. Each station buffer can be over 1,2,3... polygons and those can be completly different polygons.

I would like to have data on how much of the buffer is filled by each polygon but I was not able to find a function or a way to do it. So for example for point A I would have that in the buffer of 5km there is 80% of polygon B and 20% of polygon C as the output, so 4 values, two for IDs of the polygons and 2 for the percentage overlap (it could be only 2 values for other buffer or 6 etc. etc.).

Main difference to the other similar question provided is that I have 2 vector layers (Buffer with 500 buffers and Municipalities a shape file with 500 different polygons). Previous questions were analyzing this question in situations in which I know precisely the polygons and buffers analyzed, at least that is how I understood them, so after trying to use those approaches on my dataset I was not able to replicate them.

Comment: [You other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/358118) was closed as a duplicate. This means that it has been asked before and has an answer somewhere else, namely [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339929/calculating-percentage-of-overlap-of-two-layers-in-qgis).

Comment: You have followed the duplicate link and what happens when you try the workflow? Make some kind of effort of your own

Comment: Get the total area of your buffer, then use `intersect` to get the overlapping areas between buffer and polygons, then get the area of each polygon inside each buffer, then calculate the percentage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting area percentage of overlapping polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358118/counting-area-percentage-of-overlapping-polygons)

Comment: It does not anwser my question as in my example I have a shapefile with 500 polygons and 13000 buffers. The workflows described in the previous steps do not work when I do not have a simple 1 buffer 2 polygons that I know. In my case I do not know what polygons of the shapefile are going to intersect what buffers, or even if the buffer is going to be intersected by 1,2 or more polygons.

Comment: I have also commented on the approaches posted in the previous question but did not get any response to those sadly. Bottom line being I understand those approaches and was able to replicate them in a simple setting but when I do not have specific buffers/polygons I do not know how to execute them. 

Another way of approaching this problem was to use join attributes by location -one-to-many and then getting averages of the duplicate results, only problem is that then I take average of polygons instead of their weights corresponding to % of intersection with the buffer.